# Symfony route generation with multi-valued query string parameter

Tags: symfony

Using Symfony 4.4, I'm trying to generate a route with a query string using the following code:

```php
$this->get('router')->generate('index', ['status' => ['a', 'b']]);
```

That generates `.../?status[0]=a&status[1]=b`. I would have expected it to rather be `.../?status[]=a&status[]=b`.

This is not a huge problem because the URL generated works fine but is rather inconsistent with forms as if a GET form has a multi-valued status field, submitting it would go to the latter URL.

Symfony 5.3 seems to behave similarly.

Is there a way to tell the router not to use indices in multi-valued query string parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Symfony UrlGenerator uses `http_build_query` to build query. So is not possible to change easily the behavior.

It may be possible to override/extend actual generator but I don't think is a good idea.